# CSS Match Regular Expression and last-child

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to match all elements with a class of `span1, span2, span3, span4` and so on.

I am using the following code, but it does not match the last child of these classes:

```
[class*="span"]:last-child{
    margin-left:0;
}
```

For example if I have:

```
<div>
   <div class="span3"></div>
   <div class="span9"></div>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

The rule does not apply to the `.span9` element.

Comment: Almost positive `[class*="span"]:last-child` means "apply this style if `[class*="span"]` is the last-child of an element".  You should reconsider your clearfix technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`last-child` works on whatever the last child of the parent is. In your example, it's looking at the last `div` and seeing that its class is *clearfix* - not something with *span* in it - and failing to match.

If you're always clearfixing at the end and you *only want to target the second-to-last child*, then you could use.

```css
nth-last-child(2)
```

which would, as its name suggests, target the 2nd-to-last element, regardless of what it is. [View on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/tSaQD/)

If you're always working with `div`s, you could also use this code to get the same effect:

```css
nth-last-of-type(2)
```

[View that one on JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fNvMy/)

The IE support for all of these patterns (last-child, nth-last-child, and nth-last-of-type) is the same, IE9 or later.

Though, of course, you can simply get rid of the `:last-child` bit to target all of your *span* class divs, regardless of where they are within the parent:

```
 [class*="span"]
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgtq4/)